# How to set up a WEP (legacy) Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wep, virtual-wifi

I have been searching the internet for a few days now on how to set up a WEP (in)secure AP. For pen-testing and experimentation purposes. I noticed that the support of Wired Equivalent Privacy has been dropped almost universally.

**The tools at my disposal:**

- A rooted Android device
- An Ubuntu/windows 10 desktop
- A windows 10 laptop
- A router (VTech NB403)

**What I've tried:**

- *Android hotspot* → doesn't even have WEP support and I failed to find any Hotspot app offering WEP.
- *Windows* → `netsh` doesn't work on either of my machines, failed to find any Virtual Router programs which support WEP.
- Ubuntu →`netapd` doesn't support my wireless card (no suitable drivers).
- Modem → Security option for access points only shows WPA/WPA2/None.

Any directions on how I could achieve such a setup with a WEP "protected" AP?

Comment: On Windows, enter the command `netsh wlan show drivers`. For the network card to support APs you should see `Hosted network supported : Yes`. If it does say Yes, then see [this tutorial](https://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the suggestion, in fact one of the computers (the desktop) does support Hosted network. Unfortunately it runs Windows 10 and WEP has been depreciated long ago. Only WPA is supported now.

Comment: Could you post the output of `netsh wlan show drivers`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to set up an unsecured or wep security guest network and filter by MAC address to ensure only your hardware can access it. You can do this by typing the ip address of your router into the the URL bar. You will need to login into your router as an admin and, depending on the model, click on guest network settings or wireless settings. From there there should be a toggle or box labelled enable wireless or enable guest and security options.